# Android: Recyclerview in Bottom Navigation Bar Fragment populated with SQLite will not update

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, android-bottomnav

I have a BottomNavigationBar with 3 fragments. In the first fragment, I try to put SQLite data into a recyclerview. It works fine except for the fact that I need to switch between the Navigation Bar items in order to see the refreshed recyclerview. When I use a handler with postDelayed however, it does show the refreshed recyclerview if I set around 1 sec of delay. 0.2 secs wont work already.

Even though this is still very generic: is there any best practice for this? It seems to me that I need to use AsyncTask which has been -however- deprecated.

Thanks!

Simon

**HomeFragment**

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private Context context;
    private CardView cardview;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams;
    private TextView textview;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private myDbAdapter helper;
    RecyclerView myView;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        
        helper  = new myDbAdapter(getContext());
        myView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_home);
        RecyclerViewAdapter3 adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter3(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(helper.classes())));
        myView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myView.setAdapter(adapter);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        myView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    

        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



    }

    public void refresh(View v){
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                myView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_home);
                helper  = new myDbAdapter(v.getContext());
                ArrayList<String> classes = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(helper.classes()));
                ArrayList<String> subClasses = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(helper.subClasses()));
                RecyclerViewAdapter3 adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter3(classes);
                myView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                myView.setAdapter(adapter);
                LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());
                llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                myView.setLayoutManager(llm);
            }
        }, 1000); //time in millis
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter3**

```java
public class RecyclerViewAdapter3 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter3.MyViewHolder> {
    public ArrayList<String> classArrayList;
    public ArrayList<String> subClassArrayList;
    myDbAdapter helper;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter3(ArrayList<String> classArrayList){
        this.classArrayList = classArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View listItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(listItem);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.class.setText(classArrayList.get(position));

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                helper = new myDbAdapter(v.getContext());
                helper.delete(classArrayList.get(position));
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                homeFragment.refresh(v.getRootView());
            }
        });
        holder.selectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


        }});}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return classArrayList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView class;
        private Button selectButton;
        private ImageView delete;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            class = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            selectButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectButton);
            delete = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you populate your recycler view? In which fragment lifecycle method? Or do you observe a LiveData? Please post your code, so we can better help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your code :)

There are a fair few things that can go wrong in your code as it is right now, and I can't really pinpoint what causes it to work when you use `postDelay`. I'm going to list a few, which you can look into:

From your `onClick()` inside your ViewHolder

> ```java
>    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
>    homeFragment.refresh(v.getRootView());
> ```

You should really not instantiate your fragments like this. You can instead pass a callback from your fragment to your adapter (eg.: `View.OnClickListener`)

You keep re-instantiating your adapter and your helper needlessly. You should create your adapter only once, set it as your recycler view adapter, and save it in a member variable.

### Proposed solution

I see that you're already using `ViewModel`, so you're on a great path for a less error-prone screen, so I suggest that you move your db query-ing logic to your view model. If you're using raw SQLite (instead of Room), you can extend AndroidViewModel, so you'll have access to a context right away. And as you do with your `homeViewModel.getText()`, you should expose the `classes` array as live data, observe it, and submit the new list to your adapter.

For submitting your list to your adapter I suggest using [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter), this will provide you a `submitList` method for submitting the list in the fragment, and inside the adapter, you will have a `getItem(int position)` method, which you can query inside the `onBindViewHolder` method.

### Inside your fragment, it'll look something like this:

```java
ClassAdapter adapter = null;

View onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    
    adapter = new ClassAdapter(
        new ClassDeleteCallback() {
            @Override
            void onClassDeleted(Class class) {
                // inside view model we can modify db state, than refresh live data
                viewModel.deleteClass(class);
            }
        },
        new ClassSelectedCallback() {
            // follows same pattern of above
        }
    );
    RecyclerView rv = root.findViewById(R.id.my_rv);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    
        
    homeViewModel.getClasses().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Class>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Class> classes) {
            adapter.submitList(classes);
         }
     });

    homeViewModel.refreshClasses();
    return root;
}
```

I can highly recommend for you to study this project a bit, because it covers lot of the basics which can lead to a much stabler app: [Sunflower sample app](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/GardenFragment.kt)

I think you should read a bit more about the architecture components, and then go through some code-labs and stuff, and have another go with this screen starting from square one, because it will be easier than fixing the current state :)

I hope this was helpful, and not too discouraging!

Comment: Not at all discouraging. Thanks , I will have a look :-)

Comment: @SimonKay if it helped, could you mark my answer as the solution (I'm trying to get more hats :D)